# How many layers should a neural network have?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-networks, neural-computing

Are there any advantages of having more than 2 hidden layers in a Neural Network?

I've seen some places that recommend it, others prove that there is no advantage.

Which one is right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One very good resource is the [Neural Network FAQ](ftp://ftp.sas.com/pub/neural/FAQ.html). The question depends a lot on your problem. If the problem is linear in nature, there is no reason to have any hidden layers. If the problem is non-linear, often a single hidden layer with around 10 hidden neurons will do the trick.

There is a very similar question (with a very similar answer) at CrossValidated: [How to choose the number of hidden layers and nodes in a feedforward neural network?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181/how-to-choose-the-number-of-hidden-layers-and-nodes-in-a-feedforward-neural-netw))